# Менять текст при нажатии на button туда и обратно

Tags: javascript, php, html

Буду рад вашей помощи.
сделал скрипт для того, что бы при нажатии на кнопку текст менялся, все классно, но  понадобился скрипт с такой же функцией только которая будет работать "вперед назад"  то есть при нажатии на кнопку меняется текст, еще раз нажимаем на кнопку, текст возвращается тот что был.
Прошу помочь доработать предоставленный ниже скрипт под эту функцию)
Спасибо.

```js
    $('#showHideContent').click(function() {
    $("#showHideContent").html('Свернуть');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContent").click(function () {
        if ($("#content_Box_Div").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#content_Box_Div").show("slow");
        } else {
            $("#content_Box_Div").hide("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><button class="btn btn_wallet_usd" id="showHideContent" style="max-width: 100px; border: none; outline: none;">Развернуть</button></center>
      <div id="content_Box_Div" style="display:none;">
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест тест</div>
      </div>
```

Нужна помощь в доработке вот этого кусочка

```
    $('#showHideContent').click(function() {
$("#showHideContent").html('Свернуть');
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```js
$('#showHideContent').click(function() {
    $("#showHideContent").html($("#showHideContent").html() === 'Свернуть'? 'Развернуть' :'Свернуть');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContent").click(function () {
        if ($("#content_Box_Div").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#content_Box_Div").show("slow");
        } else {
            $("#content_Box_Div").hide("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><button class="btn btn_wallet_usd" id="showHideContent" style="max-width: 100px; border: none; outline: none;">Развернуть</button></center>
      <div id="content_Box_Div" style="display:none;">
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест тест</div>
      </div>
```

Или используя  переменную :

```js
let open = false;
$('#showHideContent').click(function() {
    $("#showHideContent").html(open = !open? 'Свернуть': 'Развернуть');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContent").click(function () {
        if ($("#content_Box_Div").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#content_Box_Div").show("slow");
        } else {
            $("#content_Box_Div").hide("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><button class="btn btn_wallet_usd" id="showHideContent" style="max-width: 100px; border: none; outline: none;">Развернуть</button></center>
      <div id="content_Box_Div" style="display:none;">
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест Тест</div>
      <div class="pay_text"><img src="{{frontend}}/templates/default/images/svg/diamond.svg" alt="" witht="15" height="15">Тест тест</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, с переменной гораздо лучше, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Prakctoleb всегда пожалуйста